# .after() jquery em JS Puro?

Tags: javascript

Em jquery:

```
$( "#main article:nth-child(3)" ).after( "<div style='clear:both;/>" );
```

Como ficaria em JS puro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`insertAdjacentHTML(posição, conteúdo)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) <sup>[(suporte)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=insertadjacenthtml)</sup>:

A **`posição`** é definida em relação ao elemento pelos tipos seguintes:

- `"afterbegin"`: Dentro do elemento, antes de seu primeiro filho (`childNode`).
- `"afterend"`: Após o próprio elemento.
- `"beforebegin"`: Antes do próprio elemento.
- `"beforeend"`:  Dentro do elemento, após seu último filho (`childNode`).

E o posicionamento ficaria:

```html
<!-- beforebegin -->
<p>
<!-- afterbegin -->
foo 
<!-- beforeend -->
</p>
<!-- afterend -->`
```

O **`conteúdo`** é string a ser analisada como HTML ou XML e inserido na árvore.

---

#### Exemplo:

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector('p');
elemento.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>Overflow</p>');
```

```css
p { display: inline }
```

```html
<p>Stack</p>
```

Comment: boa resposta, `+1`. Pelo que vi da documentação a função  `insertAdjacentHTML` aceita HTML como texto mas não um elemento criado por exemplo com `createElement`. Entretanto o Chrome e o IE tem um método [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536451(v=vs.85).aspx), mesmo não existindo tal método na recomendação W3C

Answer (score 8):

A função jQuery `.after()` insere um elemento irmão depois, em javascript nativo isso é feito com [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), segundo a documentação:

> (`insertBefore`) Adiciona o nó especificado, antes de um elemento de referência, como filho do nó atual.
>
> (...)
>
> Não existe um método `insertAfter`. Mas ele pode ser emulado combinando o método `insertBefore` com [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

Dessa forma deve-se inserir o novo nó no elemento pai antes do próximo elemento irmão.

A forma curta fica:

```js
elemento.parent.insertBefore(novoElemento, elemento.nextSibling);
```

O código abaixo adiciona um novo nó como é feito na pergunta, é de fácil compreensão e os comentários complementam.

```js
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('span:nth-child(3)');
var elemento, pai, div;
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
  elemento = elementos[i];
  pai = elemento.parentNode;
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.clear = 'both';
  // insere no elemento pai, antes do próximo irmão
  pai.insertBefore(div, elemento.nextSibling)
  // se o segundo parâmetro é nulo será inserido como último filho
}

// se for apenas um elemento utilize a linha abaixo
// e apague o loop for
var elemento = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(3)');
```

```html
<span>item</span>
<span>item</span>
<span>item</span>
<span>item</span>
```

Comment: Bem visto, `++`